# Coin Slider: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm trying to implement Coin Slider (http://workshop.rs/2010/04/coin-slider-image-slider-with-unique-effects/) on my website. However, I can't get it to work. Firefox error console brings up '$ is not defined'.

I only really know HTML and CSS and thought this would just be a case of copying and pasting code. If it's something simple to fix that would be great, but I may have bitten off more than I can chew!

Thanks for any help.

```
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="coin-slider.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css" />
<style type="text/css">
</style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
<!-- Begin Content -->
     <div id="content">
    <div id='coin-slider'>
     <a href="" target="">
    <img src='../portfoliopages/Funpets/splashpresliced.jpg' >
      <span>
      Description for img01
    </span>
    </a>
    <a href="" target="">
      <img src='../portfoliopages/Funpets/eggprespliced.jpg' >
     <span>
     Description for imgN
     </span>
     </a>
    <a href="" target="">
    <img src='../portfoliopages/Funpets/baby.jpg' >
      <span>
      Description for img01
    </span>
    </a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#coin-slider').coinslider({ width: 550,
    height: 220,
    spw: 7,
    sph: 5,
    delay: 3000,
    sDelay: 30,
    opacity: 0.7,
    titleSpeed: 500,
    effect: '',
    navigation: true,
    links : true,
    hoverPause: true });
    });
    </script
    </div>
    </div>
     <!-- End Content -->
    </div>
    </div>
<!-- Begin Footer --></div> </div>
     <!-- End Footer -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Have you made sure, that the JS file `jquery-1.4.2.js` is in the same directory as the HTML?

Comment: Could you expand on that error message. Surely there are filenames and linenumbers attached to it. Or perhaps even a stack trace.

Comment: Stack trace? It isn't quite that complicated. '$ is not defined' just means the jQuery library wasn't found. Furthermore, OP should be using latest jQuery, not 1.4.2.

Answer (score 1):

The error $ is not defined is typical when the page cannot find jQuery or jQuery is being referenced before it's loaded. In your instance jQuery is being loaded first so I'd assume your path to jQuery is wrong. Double check the path to jquery and that you can browse to the jquery JS file jquery-1.4.2.js

Comment: No, that *is* the answer. That particular JS error is shown when jQuery was not found.

Comment: I've got it working now, thanks. I hadn't included the jquery-1.4.2.min.js file. I'm glad it was something simple.

Answer (score 1):

That means the jQuery variable `$` is not defined. I guess you just copypasted without downloading jQuery.

This particular piece of code requires you to have downloaded jQuery, named the file `jquery-1.4.2.js` and locatde it in the same place as this file. You should get the `coin-slider.min.js` there as well. You can probably find it attached to the tutorial.

Comment: I'd downloaded the files that came with the tutorial, but the jquery-1.4.2.min.js file wasn't included. I've found it now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have no 404 errors while loading the page. Enable FireBug in firefox and go the the Net setting, reload the page and check your http responses (Or any other Debugger/Inspect tool)

You can try replacing your script source to full URLs to test if your code is working :

For Jquery : http://workshop.rs/projects/coin-slider/jquery-1.4.2.min.js

For Coin Slider : http://workshop.rs/projects/coin-slider/coin-slider.min.js

I got the full urls from the Coin Slider example/demo page. You can open the links and download it to your local machine.

Comment: I've got it working now! Thanks. The jquery-1.4.2.min.js file wasn't bundled with the download, so I got it from your link.